# Overwrite $_SESSION Variable After Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

Is it possible to overwrite the following input variable? After refreshing the page, it doesn't update this session variable.

```
<td data-th="Price"><input type="number" class="form-control text-center" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['shopping-cart']['quantity']; ?>"> </td>
```

Comment: please provide some more info about this problem

Comment: Last time I did post a extensive post on this subject, however I didn't get a response. That's why I kept it short and simple. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61878646/html-input-variable-overwrite-the-session-variable-php

Comment: I voted to close this a a duplicate of your existing question. _“That's why I kept it short and simple”_ - you so massively over-“simplified” this now here, that it is not even clear what you are actually asking. You have shown us something that _outputs_ a value only, not even the part where this value gets set or updated.